# Add virtual attribute to a model that is located in a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that is located somewhere in the gem - `PgSearch::Document`. Can I add a virtual attribute to it? It seems to me this code does not work:

**app/models/concerns/pg_search.rb:**

```
module PgSearch
  class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :my_virtual_attribute
    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

While *"It seems to me this code does not work:"* is not very descriptive and you have provided no context for reasoning or usage.

I would recommend the following implementation (located in config/initializers/[some_identifiable_file_name].rb) to ensure this virtual attribute addition is loaded when the application is initialized

```
module DocumentExtension
  def self.extended(mod) 
    mod.instance_eval { attr_accessor :my_virtual_attribute } 
  end 
end 

PgSearch::Document.extend(DocumentExtension)
```